# ElasticBeanstalk Token Vending on iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having trouble with the anonymous vending machine hosting on elastic beanstalk. The situation is that I'm using the code that AWS provides for iOS, but getting 500s back for the crypto generated uid / key that the KeyWrapper makes. The beanstalk logs seem to be pretty sparse but are showing the 500s, so they are at least talking.

This null pointer exception seems to be the only detailed error, although I am not sure what problem it is pointing towards.

```
May 10, 2013 4:10:48 PM com.amazonaws.tvm.GetTokenServlet processRequest
INFO: processing request
May 10, 2013 4:10:48 PM com.amazonaws.tvm.anonymous.AnonymousTokenVendingMachine validateTokenRequest
FINE: Timestamp [ 2013-05-10T16%3A10%3A48Z ] is valid
May 10, 2013 4:10:48 PM com.amazonaws.tvm.anonymous.AnonymousTokenVendingMachine validateTokenRequest
FINE: Signature matched!!!
May 10, 2013 4:10:48 PM com.amazonaws.tvm.TemporaryCredentialManagement getTemporaryCredentials
SEVERE: Exception during getTemporaryCredentials
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:712)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:823)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2201)
    at com.amazonaws.tvm.TemporaryCredentialManagement.getPolicyObject(TemporaryCredentialManagement.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.tvm.TemporaryCredentialManagement.getTemporaryCredentials(TemporaryCredentialManagement.java:42)
    at com.amazonaws.tvm.anonymous.AnonymousTokenVendingMachine.getToken(AnonymousTokenVendingMachine.java:88)
    at com.amazonaws.tvm.GetTokenServlet.processRequest(GetTokenServlet.java:48)
    at com.amazonaws.tvm.RootServlet.doGet(RootServlet.java:38)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
May 10, 2013 4:10:48 PM com.amazonaws.tvm.GetTokenServlet processRequest
SEVERE: Error generating session credentials for UID : 6c6feea6848c6ca41c4a9e427896dba9
May 10, 2013 4:10:48 PM com.amazonaws.tvm.GetTokenServlet processRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old question. But I also encountered the same problem while running a TVM in the environment (Amazon beanstalk micro instance) This issue has been solved once I restarted the beanstalk instance. But to make sure that you are not getting this error again, you have to make sure that the user policy of the IAM user who is used to access the TVM, is copied to the "TokenVendingMachinePolicy.json" file which is in the deployed TVM application. for further details refer http://aws.amazon.com/code/8872061742402990

Comment: @ Ronak - I think I should be posting this as a comment rather than an answer. Please let me know which is the most appropriate (or may be if you want me to remove the answer).. I just wanted to help by giving a clue to someone who encounter the same issue.

Comment: Answer should be more appropriate,.... I appreciate your way of helping him... but from this question might be helpful to anyone like us if and only if it is having good answers.... with roper description... If you are unable to comment then earn some more points and then post it. this site is used by professional users and they dont want to waste time in just reading comments in answer section.. so i suggest you to better remove this or if you are having more information then please edit your answer...

Comment: @ Ronak- Thanks for the heads up. Since there is no way for me to add this as a comment I updated the answer itself with the root cause. May this help somebody!!!